# Datagridview select last insert row what i insert via database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I want to select row what is last insert in database. When i insert data in database datagridview is refreshed and he retrive last row what i insert. My problem is that i no have idea how to select last insert row. I have last insert id and how now to 
[image]

When i click on save button new item is added to database, grid is refreshed and he show new row.How to automaticly after success save data select row like **id 30 in grid**

```
private void sacuvajPromeneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var pleaseWaitForm = new Loading())
    {
        pleaseWaitForm.Show();

        Application.DoEvents();

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Database.connStringStatic))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ime", primalac_ime_textBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prezime", primalac_prezime_textBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grupa_id", 1);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ulica", primalac_ulica_textBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grad", primalac_grad_textBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postanski_br", primalac_postanskiBroj_textBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jmbg", posiljalac_jmb_textBox2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefon", primalac_kontakt_textBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefon_2", telefon2_textBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", posiljalac_email_textBox3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@napomena", napomenarichTextBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum_kreiranja", DateTime.Now);

                   // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "CALL kreiraj_korisnika(@ime, @prezime, @grupa_id, @ulica, @grad, @postanski_br, @jmbg, @telefon, @telefon_2, @email, @napomena, @datum_kreiranja)";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    long lastInsertId= cmd.LastInsertedId;

                    // Refresh grid
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                    bs.DataSource = GetDat("SELECT id, ime, prezime, ulica, grad, postanski_br, telefon FROM korisnici ORDER by id");
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;


                   // Test selecting


                    pleaseWaitForm.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("User created.");

                    // Now select that new created user in grid
                   // dataGridView1.Rows[4].Selected = true;


                    this.Activate();

                    sacuvajPromeneButton.Visible = false;


                }
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the newest added row by handling `DataGridViewRowsAddedEvent`:

```
private void DataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above does not work.

Make the following changes.

Then, set the multi-select option to false.

```
private void DataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```